# Remove BOM from files

Tags: php, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark)

As you can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565349/somehow-php-broke-doctype) I`m fighting with BOM in my files. Can you recommend me linux console tool to remove BOM from all files in current/sub directory ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom ; there are some answer you should like ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark

Comment: IN PHP http://blog.philipp-michels.de/?p=32