# fighting the BOM in php

Tags: php, mysql, byte-order-mark

I've coded my php script in `Coda` for mac. everything was great until I published the script on the web. the first problem was that `session_start()` won't work even in line 1. However, the solution is there was `BOM` bytes in the file which caused the problem. Then I moved all my files to my windows computer and run them on `notpad++` and saved all the files in `UTF-8 Without BOM`. The session work's now, but I've found some characters in some of my files such as the `login.php` in my script.

The characters are like this: `ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ ï»¿ï»¿`

I've searched the web and reviewed these topics

[Remove BOM from files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565803/remove-bom-from-files)

[Elegant way to search for UTF-8 files with BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom)

[Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark)

but still the same :(

Thank's in advance.

See the picture for more information about the characters.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple php files via `include`'s? Probably you forgot to remove from any of those